# Can I say "Please find my yesterday’s and today’s daily reports in the documents."

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Can I say "Please find my yesterday’s and today’s daily reports in the documents."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot say "Please find my yesterday’s and today’s daily reports in the documents."

You can say:

> Please find yesterday’s and today’s daily reports in the documents. (as suggested by Steve Melnikoff)

Or, you can also say:

> Please find my daily reports from yesterday and today in the documents. (as suggested by Bruno Rothgiesser)

Answer (score 6):

**No**.

In general English disallows using two different direct possessives together in the some noun phrase. Using possessive *my* and possessive *tomorrow's* to modify the word *reports* results in a sentence that I find ungrammatical. One of the possessives must be demoted to a prepositional phrase, and since *my* cannot be so demoted (since **of me* is ungrammatical for other reasons), you have to move *tomorrow* to a prepositional phrase:

> Please find my daily reports from yesterday and today in the documents.

(This is the same corrected version that Bruno gave, but unlike Bruno I find the original to be ungrammatical, and the corrected version to be necessary, not just stylistically preferred.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because:

1. You can use a possessive pronoun followed by a word with 's (i.e. the [saxon genitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_genitive)). For example, "my last year's tax refund".
2. You can use 's in more than one word in the same sentence. For example, "Here you can review yesterday's, today's and tomorrow's horoscope."

Having said that, I would reword your sentence to make it sound more natural:

> Please find my daily reports from
>   yesterday and today  in the documents.

Comment: Or omit "my": Please find yesterday’s and today’s daily reports in the documents.

Comment: Point #1 is not valid for this case, because in your example, *my* is modifying *sister*, but in the question, *my* is attempting to modify *daily reports*, going around the genitive, which is not grammatical.  I'm surprised it doesn't just sound ungrammatical to you.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, I agree that point #1 is not a good example. I'm changing the example in my post. However, that does not make the sentence ungrammatical. It just does not sound natural.

Comment: @Bruno: Native speakers don't write such sentences, and it doesn't follow prescribed rules either.  Is there another metric you are using to determine grammaticality?  If I saw a sentence like the one in the question, or the one in your answer, I would assume the person was a non-native speaker.

Comment: yeah it sounds ungrammatical to me too

Comment: I don't think "yes" is a good answer. English isn't about whether or not things are acceptable by a set of rules. "Rules" should follow common usage, and the above sentence sounds quite wrong.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, @Claudiu: we all agreed that the sentence did not sound natural and that people would not in general use it. The point with which we disagreed was whether this really made the sentence ungrammatical. If it doesn't violate any rule, I don't see why it would be ungrammatical. But, honestly, this is not really relevant. It's what people use that matters. That's why I suggested since the beginning an alternative wording for the sentence. Anyway, one of the best things about this site is that we can all post answers and choose the ones that sound right to us.

Comment: @Bruno: Descriptive linguists who study syntax use "would not use" and "does not sound natural" as *the* indicator of ungrammaticality.